# Finding paths in a subdivision of $K_5$

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Some years ago (during my master's thesis), I studied a problem known as *Kotzig's conjecture* (however not this [famous one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graceful_labeling), but the lesser known one on $k$-paths in graphs).

Anyway, there was no way to solve the problem, but I was able to distill one specific instance of a sub-problem, that seemed easy enough.
Still, I was not able to solve it. Here it is.

> **Question.**
>
> Take the $K_5$ (complete graph on $5$ vertices), and subdivide its edges by inserting new vertices (see the image below). There is only one condition: as you can see, I suggestively used different colors for the edges to divide the graph into an "outer cycle" and an "inner cycle". The condition now is, that both cycles must have the same number of vertices in it, i.e., both cycles must have the same length, say $k+1$.
>
> Do there always exists two (not necessarily intersection-free) paths $P_1$ and $P_2$ of length $k$, that start in the same vertex, and end in the same vertex?

[image]

I made the experience, that given any specific instance of the problem, I had no trouble finding such a double-$k$-path.
But I found it very hard (even impossible), to give a general construction of such one.
I had a lot of heuristics, but the conditions for their applications where complicated.

The following image shows two 12-paths in the above subdivision with 13-cycles.

[image]

Comment: If I understand correctly, https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0012365X93E0106E answers this question for $k \ge 12$, so there are only a small number of instances to check to completely answer it.

Comment: @PeterTaylor The paper is known to contain an error (as noted by R. Häggkvist in the year 2000). Instead, the conjecture is proven for $k\le 20$ by Kostochka, and open for $k\ge 21$ (you can also find this in "Proofs from THE BOOK" by Aigner/Ziegler). But this conjecture is only of secondary interest for the question I asked here. I ask about a problem motivated by it, but not equivalent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Label the vertices of the original $K_5$ as $u_i\;(i \in [1,5])$. Let $w_{i,j}\;(i,j \in [1,5])$ be one greater than the number of vertices inserted in the edge $u_i - u_j$. Then we can label those intermediate vertices $v_{i,j,a}$ numbered $u_i - v_{i,j,1} - v_{i,j,2} - \cdots - v_{i,j,w_{i,j}-1} - u_j$ with identification $v_{i,j,a} = v_{j,i,w_{i,j}-a}$.

The generation constraint is that $w_{1,2} + w_{2,3} + w_{3,4} + w_{4,5} + w_{1,5} = w_{1,3} + w_{3,5} + w_{2,5} + w_{2,4} + w_{1,4} = k + 1$.

Let $G_5$ denote the original $K_5$ with weights $w_{i,j}$, and $G_5 \setminus (u_i, u_j)$ denote the graph obtained by deleting edge $(u_i, u_j)$ from $G_5$.

Denote the shared endpoints of $P_1$ and $P_2$ as $s$ and $t$.

There are five cases:

- $s = u_i, t = u_j$ are both vertices of $G_5$. Then the two paths $s -^* t$ in the subdivided graph have the same weights as the paths in $G_5$ which pass through the same vertices in the same order. Since $w_{i,j} \le k - 3$ we can ignore the direct edge $u_i - u_j$, so we're looking for two paths $u_i -^* u_j$ in $G_5 \setminus (u_i, u_j)$ of weight $k$.
- $s = u_i$ is a vertex of $G_5$, and $t = v_{i,j,a}$ is an intermediate vertex on an edge from $s$. Since again a direct approach is too short, we're looking for two paths $u_i -^* u_j$ in $G_5 \setminus (u_i, u_j)$ of weight $k - (w_{i,j} - a)$.
- $s = v_{i,j,a}, t = v_{i,j,b}, a < b$ are intermediate vertices on the same edge. We can increment or decrement $a$ and $b$ together, so this doesn't add anything to the previous case.
- $s = u_i$ is a vertex of $G_5$, and $t = v_{h,j,a}$ is an intermediate vertex on an edge independent of $s$. Then we can have two paths through $u_h$ (i.e. paths $u_i -^* u_h$ in $G_5 \setminus (u_h,u_j)$ of weight $k - a$), two paths through $u_j$ (i.e. paths $u_i -^* u_j$ in $G_5 \setminus(u_h, u_j)$ of weight $k - (w_{h,j} - a)$), or one of each.
- $s = v_{i,j,a}, t = v_{m,n,b}$ are intermediate vertices on different edges. Then there are four options, which follow the previous patterns.

Put together, we get a giant but finite disjunction of conjunctions of inequalities which we can negate and feed to a satisfiability solver such as Z3.

---

To generate the Z3 source I'm using Python. I'll probably come back to this and try to tidy it up a bit. It turned out not to be necessary to fully cover the final case. I realise that computer proofs aren't as satisfactory as non-computer proofs, but at least knowing that it's a theorem is a good starting point.

```
from itertools import permutations, combinations

for i, j in combinations(range(1, 6), 2):
    print("(declare-const w{}{} Int)".format(i, j))
print("(declare-const k Int)")

for i, j in combinations(range(1, 6), 2):
    print("(assert (> w{}{} 0))".format(i, j))
print("(assert (= (+ w12 w23 w34 w45 w15) (+ w13 w35 w25 w24 w14) (+ k 1)))")

# Assert the non-existence of two paths of length k between the same vertices
print("(assert (not(or")


def path_weight(path):
    rv = "(+"
    u = path[0]
    for v in path[1:]:
        rv += " w{}{}".format(min(u, v), max(u, v))
        u = v
    rv += ")"
    return rv

def paths(s, t, excluded_edges):
    s, t = min(s, t), max(s, t)
    excluded_edges = ["w{}{}".format(min(i, j), max(i, j)) for i, j in excluded_edges]

    paths_st = set()
    other_vertices = set(range(1, 6))
    other_vertices.remove(s)
    other_vertices.remove(t)
    for pathlen in range(0, 4):
        for intermediates in permutations(other_vertices, pathlen):
            path = tuple([s] + list(intermediates) + [t])
            path_str = path_weight(path)
            if not any(excluded_edge in path_str for excluded_edge in excluded_edges):
                paths_st.add(path)
    return paths_st

def w(i, j):
    return "w{}{}".format(min(i, j), max(i, j))


for i, j in combinations(range(1, 6), 2):
    # Case 1: two paths from i to j of length k
    # Cases 2 and 3: two paths from i to j of length (k + 1 - w{i}{j}) <= x < k
    # Combined cases 1 to 3: two paths from i to j of length (k + 1 - w{i}{j}) <= x <= k
    paths_ij = paths(i, j, [(i, j)])
    for p1, p2 in combinations(paths_ij, 2):
        path_weight_1 = path_weight(p1)
        path_weight_2 = path_weight(p2)
        #print("\t(and (= path_weight_1 path_weight_2) (<= (+ k 1) (+ path_weight_1 wij)) (<= path_weight_1 k))")
        print("\t(and (= {} {}) (<= (+ k 1) (+ {} {})) (<= {} k))".format(path_weight_1, path_weight_2, path_weight_1, w(i,j), path_weight_1))

for h, j in combinations(range(1, 6), 2):
    avail = set(range(1, 6))
    avail.remove(h)
    avail.remove(j)
    for i in avail:
        # Case 4: two kinds of path: h-*i of weight k-a or h-*j of weight k+a-w_{h,j}, disallowing edge h-j.
        paths_ih = paths(i, h, [(h, j)])
        paths_ij = paths(i, j, [(h, j)])

        for p1, p2 in combinations(paths_ih, 2):
            path_weight_1 = path_weight(p1)
            path_weight_2 = path_weight(p2)
            print("\t(and (= {} {}) (<= (+ k 1) (+ {} {})) (<= (+ {} 1) k))".format(path_weight_1, path_weight_2, path_weight_1, w(h,j), path_weight_1))

        for p1, p2 in combinations(paths_ij, 2):
            path_weight_1 = path_weight(p1)
            path_weight_2 = path_weight(p2)
            print("\t(and (= {} {}) (<= (+ k 1) (+ {} {})) (<= (+ {} 1) k))".format(path_weight_1, path_weight_2, path_weight_1, w(h,j), path_weight_1))

        for p1 in paths_ih:
            path_weight_1 = path_weight(p1)
            for p2 in paths_ij:
                path_weight_2 = path_weight(p2)
                # path_weight_1 = (k - a) and path_weight_2 = k - (w_{h,j} - a) and 0 < a < w_{h,j}
                # Rearrange: 0 < a = k - path_weight_1 = path_weight_2 - k + w_{h,j} < w_{h,j}
                #   2k = path_weight_1 + path_weight_2 + w_{h,j}
                #   path_weight_1 < k
                #   path_weight_2 < k
                print("\t(and (= (+ k k) (+ {} {} {})) (< {} k) (< {} k))".format(path_weight_1, path_weight_2, w(h,j), path_weight_1, path_weight_2))

# How to keep this from getting too messy?
# s = v_{i,j,a}  t = v_{m,n,b}
# Two paths in G_5 \ {(u_i, u_j), (u_m, u_n)}
# * Two paths through u_i -* u_m            so i != m
for i in range(1, 6):
    for j in (x for x in range(1, 6) if x != i):
        for m in (x for x in range(1, 6) if x != i):
            for n in (x for x in range(1, 6) if x != m):
                if sorted([i, j]) == sorted([m, n]): continue
                paths_im = paths(i, m, [(i, j), (m, n)])
                for p1, p2 in combinations(paths_im, 2):
                    path_weight_1 = path_weight(p1)
                    path_weight_2 = path_weight(p2)
                    # Two paths i-*m of same weight, between k-(w_{i,j}-1)-(w_{m,n}-1) and k-2
                    print("\t(and (= {} {}) (<= (+ k 2) (+ {} {} {})) (<= (+ {} 2) k))".format(path_weight_1, path_weight_2, path_weight_1, w(i,j), w(m,n), path_weight_1))

# * One path through u_i -* u_m and one through u_i -* u_n          i != m, i != n
for i in range(1, 6):
    for j in (x for x in range(1, 6) if x != i):
        for m, n in combinations((x for x in range(1, 6) if x != i), 2):
            paths_im = paths(i, m, [(i, j), (m, n)])
            paths_in = paths(i, n, [(i, j), (m, n)])
            for p1 in paths_im:
                path_weight_1 = path_weight(p1)
                for p2 in paths_in:
                    path_weight_2 = path_weight(p2)
                    # s = v_{i,j,a}  t = v_{m,n,b}
                    # 
                    # a + path_weight_1 + b = a + path_weight_2 + w_{m,n} - b = k
                    # 1 <= a <= w_{i,j} - 1
                    # 1 <= b <= w_{m,n} - 1
                    #
                    # 2b = path_weight_2 + w_{m,n} - path_weight_1
                    # 2a = 2k - (path_weight_1 + path_weight_2 + w_{m,n})
                    #
                    # (= 0 (% (+ path_weight_1 path_weight_2 w_{m,n}) 2))
                    # (<= (+ 2 path_weight_1 path_weight_2 w_{m,n}) (+ k k))
                    # (<= (+ k k 2) (+ w_{i,j} w_{i,j} path_weight_1 path_weight_2 w_{m,n}))
                    # (<= (+ 2 path_weight_1) (+ path_weight_2 w_{m,n}))
                    # (<= (+ 2 path_weight_2 w_{m,n}) (+ path_weight_1 w_{m,n} w_{m,n}))
                    print(("\t(and (= 0 (mod (+ {} {} {}) 2)) " +
                           "(<= (+ 2 {} {} {}) (+ k k)) " +
                           "(<= (+ k k 2) (+ {} {} {} {} {})) " +
                           "(<= (+ 2 {}) (+ {} {})) " +
                           "(<= (+ 2 {} {}) (+ {} {} {})))").format(
                               path_weight_1, path_weight_2, w(m,n),
                               path_weight_1, path_weight_2, w(m,n),
                               w(i,j), w(i,j), path_weight_1, path_weight_2, w(m,n),
                               path_weight_1, path_weight_2, w(m,n),
                               path_weight_2, w(m,n), path_weight_1, w(m,n), w(m,n)))


# * One path through u_i -* u_m and one through u_j -* u_n
# Turns out not to be necessary.

print(")))")

print("(check-sat)")
```

Comment: Many thanks for the work you put into this! I am not very familiar with computer proofs etc., so can you explain me a little bit more what exactly happened here? You generated code that check whether a given instance is solvable? Or you were able to prove it for all instances but the proof is computer generated and hence not in a readable form?

Comment: Basically I asked the computer to find a counterexample and it said there are none. I'm beyond the limit of what I fully understand (I understand SAT, and the common techniques used in SAT solvers, but I've never studied "solving modulo theories"). However, Z3 is well regarded so if there is an error it's almost certainly in my formulation of the problem. I included my Python code so it can be checked.

Comment: That is amazing! I will have to check this out. I mentioned that the posted problem is a special case, and I now wonder whether the general case can be treated with the same idea. In my question, we have two (edge-disjoint)  $(k+1)$-cycles intersecting in $s=5$ points (multi-edges are okay). The general case is $s\ge 2$. I solved all cases $s\le 4$ and the $K_5$-case of this post was the only open case for $s=5$. Do you think there is a way to formulate a SAT instance for the general case with general $s\ge 5$?

Comment: I don't see it. The structure of the weighted $K_5$ is the very core of the way I've encoded the problem: I could adapt it to any other fixed graph, but even to check $K_n$ for general $n$ would require a different approach, using first order logic (for which we might get lucky or the theorem prover might fail to give an answer).

Comment: Wait, I'm being stupid. Other $K_n$ aren't covered by two cycles.

Comment: Ok, I see. We have one cycle $u_1 - u_2 - \cdots - u_n - u_1$ and one $u_{\pi(1)} - \cdots$. I wonder whether Z3 has support for permutations...